Converting string to datetime with milliseconds and timezone - Pyspark
I have the following 3 time records(Originally it is coming as String) to be converted to timestamp.
CreateDate
2022-01-24 08:37:21.6670097 -06:00
2022-01-26 14:11:54.1950238 -06:00
2022-12-28 09:05:35.4445072 -06:00

I tried the following
df = df.withColumn('CreateDate', sf.to_timestamp('CreateDate', "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z"))

And after process, the dataframe is showing as null. Instead the values should be converted to timestamp with time zone format.

See docs for format specifiers.
You're using:

SSS, should be using SSSSSSS -- this is unusual. It's usually micro (3-digits) or nano (6-digits) seconds.
Z, should be using ZZZZZ


Fraction: Use one or more (up to 9) contiguous 'S' characters, e,g SSSSSS, to parse and format fraction of second. For parsing, the acceptable fraction length can be [1, the number of contiguous ‘S’]. For formatting, the fraction length would be padded to the number of contiguous ‘S’ with zeros. Spark supports datetime of micro-of-second precision, which has up to 6 significant digits, but can parse nano-of-second with exceeded part truncated.


Offset Z: This formats the offset based on the number of pattern letters. One, two or three letters outputs the hour and minute, without a colon, such as ‘+0130’. The output will be ‘+0000’ when the offset is zero. Four letters outputs the full form of localized offset, equivalent to four letters of Offset-O. The output will be the corresponding localized offset text if the offset is zero. Five letters outputs the hour, minute, with optional second if non-zero, with colon. It outputs ‘Z’ if the offset is zero. Six or more letters will fail.

>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(dstr=[
... ('2022-01-24 08:37:21.6670097 -06:00',),
... ('2022-01-26 14:11:54.1950238 -06:00',),
... ('2022-12-28 09:05:35.4445072 -06:00',),
... ], schema='dstr: string')
>>> 
>>> df = df.withColumn('CreateDate', sf.to_timestamp('dstr', "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS ZZZZZ"))
>>> df.collect()
[
Row(dstr='2022-01-24 08:37:21.6670097 -06:00', CreateDate=datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 24, 8, 37, 21, 667009)), 
Row(dstr='2022-01-26 14:11:54.1950238 -06:00', CreateDate=datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 26, 14, 11, 54, 195023)), 
Row(dstr='2022-12-28 09:05:35.4445072 -06:00', CreateDate=datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 28, 9, 5, 35, 444507))
]
>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+----------------------------------+--------------------------+
|dstr                              |CreateDate                |
+----------------------------------+--------------------------+
|2022-01-24 08:37:21.6670097 -06:00|2022-01-24 08:37:21.667009|
|2022-01-26 14:11:54.1950238 -06:00|2022-01-26 14:11:54.195023|
|2022-12-28 09:05:35.4445072 -06:00|2022-12-28 09:05:35.444507|
+----------------------------------+--------------------------+

>>>

